# PyLint vs f-strings

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, pylint

Quick question. I have the following code.

```
import math #importar el modulo Math

def pi_round(value): #Funcion que redondea Pi
    if value>15:
        return f"Bueno, tecnicamente pi no llega taaaan lejos. El valor de pi completo es: {math.pi}"
    else:
        return f"El valor redondeado de pi es {round(math.pi,value)}"


if __name__=="__main__":
    while True: #Revisar que el valor sea un numero
        try:
            value=int(input("Ingrese hasta que valor quiere redondear pi: "))
        except:
            print("Whoops! Hubo un error. Intente Nuevamente")
        else:
            break

    print(pi_round(value))
```

Note: You can ignore the Spanish.

Well the code is very simple, but I was requested to use pylint over the code to get an evaluation. The problem is that all I get from pylint is :

```
No config file found, using default configuration
************* Module pi
E: 12, 0: invalid syntax (<string>, line 12) (syntax-error)
```

What I have in mind is that it can be a problem with f-strings because the problem seems to be on line 12 (the first f-string). But I am not sure.

Any ideas on how to fix it?

Comment: f-string is introduced in Python 3.6, which python version do you run pylint with?

Comment: To be 100% honest. I am not sure. I usually have to use python3 to run my code so I guess that the default is python 2.x. Is there any possible way to change it and make 3.x the default version?

Comment: It's easier to control which Python version you use if you run the code by the command line. Which OS do you use? Can you try running pylint from a terminal?

Comment: MacOS Catalina . Yeap, I can run it from a terminal. I just checked and pylint seems to be installed on my 2.7 packages folder (I used easy_install). I tried installing it with pip3 but it says it is already installed. Not sure what to do now.

Comment: can you try `python3 --version` and `python3 -m pylint file.py`?

Comment: got it with python3 -m pylint <filename.py> . Thanks for the info! 